# Strange js array assign bug in IE8

Tags: javascript, asp.net-ajax, internet-explorer-8

This code causes a strange bug in ie8. It comes from MicrosoftAjaxAdoNet.js in [link text](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/)

```
   function Sys$Data$_AdoNetBatchWriter$startChangeSet() {
        this._changesetBoundary = "changeset_" + this._createBoundary();
        this._changesetEntries = [];
    }
```

Before calling this function, this._changesetEntries is always null. I expected his._changesetEntries will become a empty array after this function is called. It happened as expected in chrome, firefox, ie8. It is not always true in ie8, I found that sometimes this function create a method "**indexOf(v, n)**" instead of empty array.

This strange behavior cause other bug noted in here [link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795682/ado-net-data-service-error-undefined-is-not-a-supported-http-method-in-ie8)

EDIT:I can isolate this issue from my code now, this issue occur when I use a fish-eye jquery plug-in. In this plug-in, there are something like

```
[].indexOf || (Array.prototype.indexOf = function (v, n) {
n = (n == null) ? 0 : n;
var m = this.length;
for (var i = n; i < m; i++)
if (this[i] == v) return i;
return -1;
```

})

This is a cause of this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'sometimes' in your question is the key here: under what conditions does `this._changesetEntries` get a function rather than an empty array? Some page loads? some calls to the dataService? Once you have a testcase, the answe may become more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Could you post how you're using this?  All we can do until then is speculate:

This looks like a constructor. Are you using you instantiating using `new Sys$Data$_AdoNetBatchWriter$startChangeSet()`?